# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null

Tags: json, flutter, dio

I get the error after fetching the data with Dio.

```
Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (String, dynamic) => Null))
```

I get the above error on this line `jsonResponse.forEach((key, value) {`

this is how I fetch the data from json:

```
    Future<List<AirQualityModel>> _getAirQuality() async {
var dio = Dio();
var cookieJar;
Response dioResponse;
Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
try {
  cookieJar = PersistCookieJar(dir: appDocPath + "/.cookies/");
  dio.interceptors.add(CookieManager(cookieJar));
  dioResponse = await dio.get(
      "https://www.airvisual.com/api/v2/node/5ded3e13994dfe107f7013a0");
  debugPrint('dioResponse: ' + dioResponse.data.toString());
  debugPrint("response: " + dioResponse.statusMessage.toString());
  jsonResponse = json.decode(dioResponse.data);
  airqualityList = List<AirQualityModel>();
  jsonResponse?.forEach((key, value) {
    airqualityList = (jsonResponse['current'] as List)
        .map<AirQualityModel>((j) => AirQualityModel.fromJson(j))
        .toList();
  });
  debugPrint('List: $airqualityList');
  return airqualityList;
} catch (e) {
  print('catch error: $e');
}
```

}

and this is my airquality_model.dart

```
class AirQualityModel {
final int pm25;
final int co2;
final int humidity;
final int temperature;

AirQualityModel(this.pm25, this.co2, this.humidity, this.temperature);

AirQualityModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : pm25 = json['p2'],
    co2 = json['co'],
    humidity = json['hm'],
    temperature=json['tp'];
}
```

This is my debug console:

[image]

I've updated my code and I put a set state where I decode the json and now my debug console looks like this:

```
The following RangeError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Seems like ```jsonResponse``` is null.

Comment: Where is jsonResponse populated?

Comment: @GrahamD  this.setState(() { jsonResponse = json.decode(dioResponse.data); }); here

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Reading this on my phone, bad idea I guess.

Comment: @GrahamD the debugPrints are fine.. you can see the debugprints output in the first picture they are good but I get null when I try to make the list on .forEach. I think that setState was from an example but I'm not really sure and yeah I don't need it

Comment: Your catch is trapping the error that you are trying to  assign a list to a map. However, your code then still tries to process the data. The catch should be the end of processing in the _getAirQuality method. I don't see any purpose in the setState call.

Comment: @GrahamD okay I put my catch at the end of the function and nou on my catch I get the error: ` type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: `dioResponse.data` is `Map` , you do not need to do `json.decode` again 
Step 2: `dioResponse.data["current"]` is not a `List`, you can directly use `Future<AirQualityModel>`

code snippet

```
Future<AirQualityModel> _getAirQuality() async {
    var dio = Dio();
    var cookieJar;
    Response dioResponse;
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
    try {
      cookieJar = PersistCookieJar(dir: appDocPath + "/.cookies/");
      dio.interceptors.add(CookieManager(cookieJar));
      dioResponse = await dio.get(
          "https://www.airvisual.com/api/v2/node/5ded3e13994dfe107f7013a0");

      return AirQualityModel.fromJson(dioResponse.data["current"]);
    } catch (e) {
      print('catch error: $e');
    }
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cookie_jar/cookie_jar.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:dio_cookie_manager/dio_cookie_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class AirQualityModel {
  final double pm25;
  final double co2;
  final double humidity;
  final double temperature;

  AirQualityModel(this.pm25, this.co2, this.humidity, this.temperature);

  AirQualityModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : pm25 = json['p2'].toDouble(),
        co2 = json['co'].toDouble(),
        humidity = json['hm'].toDouble(),
        temperature = json['tp'].toDouble();
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<AirQualityModel> _future;

  Future<AirQualityModel> _getAirQuality() async {
    var dio = Dio();
    var cookieJar;
    Response dioResponse;
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
    try {
      cookieJar = PersistCookieJar(dir: appDocPath + "/.cookies/");
      dio.interceptors.add(CookieManager(cookieJar));
      dioResponse = await dio.get(
          "https://www.airvisual.com/api/v2/node/5ded3e13994dfe107f7013a0");

      return AirQualityModel.fromJson(dioResponse.data["current"]);
    } catch (e) {
      print('catch error: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = _getAirQuality();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _future,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<AirQualityModel> snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return Text('none');
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              case ConnectionState.active:
                return Text('');
              case ConnectionState.done:
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text(
                    '${snapshot.error}',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Card(
                      elevation: 6.0,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 6.0, bottom: 6.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("co2  ${snapshot.data.co2.toString()}"),
                            Spacer(),
                            Text(
                              "pm25 ${snapshot.data.pm25.toString()}",
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ));
                  ;
                }
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've got one more question does it take the values from the cookies or from the Web? Because I have only. 100 requests/hour

Comment: your current code will get data from Web every time. you can use Open DevTools and check Network

Answer (score 0):

the jsonResponse might be null so check it before using it, like this `jsonResponse?.forEach((key, value)`